# SORT Transform "Remove Duplicates" in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

Quick background: I have a legal audit requirement to reproduce all steps of an SSIS package in T-SQL so that the logic can be validated.  Up until now, this hasn't been an issue.

I am trying to find the T-SQL equivalent of the SSIS SORT component - specifically when some columns are passed through (i.e. not part of the SORT key) and the option "Remove rows with duplicated sort values" is selected.

Consider the following input data:

| Item_Number | Material_Division_Number | Source_ID | Global Dimension 2 Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 905073 | NULL | 2 | 203020 |
| 905073 | 203020 | 2 | 203020 |
| 905073 | 203020 | 3 | 203020 |
| 905073 | 203020 | 4 | 203020 |
| 905073 | 203020 | 5 | 203020 |
| 905073 | 203020 | 6 | 203020 |
| 905073 | 203020 | 7 | 203020 |
| 905073 | 203020 | 8 | 203020 |
| 905073 | 203020 | 9 | 203020 |
| 905073 | 203020 | 10 | 203020 |

Where NULL is a SQL NULL.

When passed through the following SORT component configuration:

[image: SSIS SORT component configuration]

This results in the following output data:

| Item_Number | Material_Division_Number | Source_ID | Global Dimension 2 Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 905073 | 203020 | 2 | 203020 |
| 905073 | 203020 | 3 | 203020 |
| 905073 | 203020 | 4 | 203020 |
| 905073 | 203020 | 5 | 203020 |
| 905073 | 203020 | 6 | 203020 |
| 905073 | 203020 | 7 | 203020 |
| 905073 | 203020 | 8 | 203020 |
| 905073 | 203020 | 9 | 203020 |
| 905073 | 203020 | 10 | 203020 |

However, I have been unable to reproduce this behaviour in T-SQL, because it appears as though the SORT component first eliminates all columns but the ones selected for the sort key (`Source_ID`, `Item_Number`), and then re-joins back to the original dataset in order to include the columns marked as 'Pass Through' (`Material_Division_Number`, `[Global Dimension 2 Code]`), yet somehow excludes the singular row with the `NULL` value.

Ultimately this takes an input data set of 34,434 rows and reduces it to an output set of 29,972 rows and I have to be able to account for how this is working.

No combination of `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` has reproduced this behaviour.

Has anyone figured out how SSIS is performing this operation and reproduced it in T-SQL?

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item_Number, Source_ID ORDER BY Material_Division_Number DESC)` in a subquery/derived table, then filter that to `1` on the outside

Comment: However, the TSQL equivalent may or may not be the same based on your database collation. Yes, your sample data is all numeric values but be aware that string sorting in .NET (SSIS) is going to generate different results from the default database collation's sort.

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem like you actually specify how the "tie breaker" is calculated when removing the duplicates which makes me worried that perhaps the SSIS thing isn't deterministic. Or is there a explicit logic on how it does things